# Get a Message box response in Access from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, output, return-value, messagebox

I have a SQL query which adds this month's data to a data history table. So, the history table has the monthly cut-off date as a key field. I call the stored procedure from Access and it adds the data. But, if I change this months data and try to add it, obviously, it will not work because the key field already has this month's date in it. I have an IF EXISTS statement that checks whether this month is already in the History Table and, if so, then it ends the procedure.

I want to add a variable that send a message box back to Access saying something like "this date already exists, do you want to replace it?". Then , if the user clicks YES it will delete the current add and add the new data. Searching on line it seems I need an OUTPUT variable but I am struggling to understand how to use it

The SQL query I have (currently hardcoded with a month end date but will become a stored procedure with date variable) is:

```
 USE [MyDatabase]
GO
IF EXISTS(select * from [dbo].[Tbl_30_LE_Archive] where cutoff = '2022-06' )
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Already data for Period 2022-06'
 END 
ELSE

BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tbl_30_LE_Archive]
       ([CutOff]
       ,[COMMIT_ID]
       ,[Period]
       ,[Monthly]
       ,[SAP_ToDate]
       ,[ToGo]
       ,[TotalFCST])


SELECT '2022-06' as Cutoff
, Commit_ID
, Period
, Amount
, SAP_ToDate
, ToGo
, TotalFCST

 From [dbo].[MT_LE_This_Mnth] 

END

GO
```

If I run this code in SSMS it shows 'Already data for Period 2022-06' but I cannot see how to get the same result within Access if I run it as a pass through query

Comment: `PRINT` messages aren't really designed for consumption like that; they are informational only and *normally* more for debugging. Why not `THROW` it as an error, as that's what it appears to be.

Comment: If you're putting it into a stored procedure use an Output parameter and show that to the user inside ms-access

Comment: Sounds like you need two separate procedures: one to check the data, another to actually do the modification. Procedures aren't designed to be interactive, nor to receive information from the client while already running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, assuming you have that PT query setup in code (one that you use over and over in VBA? (one that eliminates the need for any connection string in code, right?).

Then use this format for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyCoolProc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE HotelName = 'My Cool' )
    BEGIN
       SELECT 'Hotel Already Exists' AS MyMessage
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
         -- DO whatever and then return message
         SELECT '' AS MyMessage
    END
END
```

And now our VBA code to call any stored procedure - including this one?

The code can look like this:

```
Sub TestFun55()

   Dim strResult       As String
   
   With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
       .SQL = "EXEC dbo.MyCoolProc"
       strResult = .OpenRecordset()(0)           
  End With
        
  If strResult <> "" Then
       MsgBox "Message from SQL = " & strResult
  End If
        
End Sub
```

So, we thus assume that the stored procedure will return a value (one row), and thus we just shove the results into the strResult, and you quite much free to then display this return value.

## Edit: how to create a query in Access

so, poster is having difficulty creating a pass-though query in Access.

So, fire up the query builder in Access.

like this:

[image]

Then close the table prompt box, this one:

[image]

Now, go to sql view, like this:

[image]

then choose pass-though from ribbon

[image]

Now display property sheet (if not already)

[image]

Ok, now setup the connection for the pt query (I will often cut + paste from a existing working query). but, you can use the connection builder (but, that's a bit of a hassle).

[image]

Now, type in a test query, a select, ANYTHING. But, for this test, lets type in our command to call/run/use the stored procedure we assume you written and setup on sql server.

this:

[image]

And now we can run that proc, and we get this:

[image]

Once the above is verified to work?

THEN and ONLY then do we go back to trying this with VBA code.

That code was/is this:

```
Sub TestFun55()

   Dim strResult       As String
   
   With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
       .SQL = "EXEC dbo.MyCoolProc"
       strResult = .OpenRecordset()(0)
       
  End With
        
  If strResult <> "" Then
       MsgBox "Message from SQL = " & strResult
  End If
        
End Sub
```

I mean, in our VBA, we COULD just run/open the query, but as above VBA code shows, we are free to change or setup the exec command in VBA - thus we can use our one qryPassR to run any SQL Server command - select query, or even the exec "some stored procedure" command.

So, get the query working BEFORE you use or try to run some VBA code.

ONLY AFTER you verify the pass-though query works, THEN you can try the above VBA code.

Comment: Thanks Albert. I am getting "invalid operation" error at strResult = .OpenRecordset()(0)   . I also guess I should add Docmd.openquery "qryPassR" before the "END With". The first part (the stored Proc) works well.

Comment: Code posted as above will work. You don't need some open query. In place of code open up the query and type in the exec my store proc and then run the query - does it work? Note that this pass through query does need to have set return records= true.

Comment: In fact after you try running the code and it fails? Open up the pt query and look at the raw SQL - (exec dbo.myproc) and verify it works by trying to run that query. In other words try running the pt query without code - does it run? So just use access and open up query and type in the exec command to run your store proc and then run the query. So test and try this before you use the VBA code - will take less than 30 seconds if your time to test

Comment: see my edits above - I show how to create a pass-though query - that seems to be your issue (creating the PT query first).

Comment: Well Albert, what can I say? Thank you very much. I am still baffled as to why I was getting the invalid operation error originally. I use PT queries a lot so I do know how to raise them but when I use the "with Currentdb.Querydefs ("qpass") " in order to use the DSN attached to that query, I always follow it with a docmd.openquery "qpass" - otherwise how does the query run?  Anyway, it works so I am very grateful.

Comment: If the store proc does not return data, then just use . execute. But to return values then we use openrecordset and that would be set MyRstP = . openrecordset. I just used (0) of the recordset to return first column. You not limited to above sample and you can do that shorthand with any recordset object. So if pt query don't return records then use.execute in place of openrecordset

Comment: Thanks Albert - you have taught me something new. I am new to SQL server as a back end to Access but really enjoying learning SQL.